Starting a venv and dbus session in a Bash script
I'm trying make a bash wrapper for my python program, but I'm running into an issue because myprogram.py needs to run in my python venv as well as within a dbus session. I've made a bash wrapper for myprogram.py and right now it looks like:
#!/bin/bash
source ./my-venv/bin/activate #activate python venv
dbus-run-session -- bash --noprofile --norc #start dbus session
echo -n 'db' | gnome-keyring-daemon --unlock #unlock keyring(using gnome bc my linux distro is headless)
python ~/myprogram.py #run my python program

This sequence of commands works in my shell, but when I put it in a bash script like this it just activates my-venv and waits for user input. Even when I start my-venv first and then run the script, it just starts my dbus session and again waits for user input. There's no issue with the gnome-keyring-daemon line as long as the above two lines work. I want it to just run the entire sequence with no user input.
How do I get myprogram.py running inside both my python venv and my dbus session with a bash script? Any help appreciated, thanks.

I'm guessing dbus-run-session creates a new shell instance and you need to pass the remaining commands as input to that somehow. Probably just run bash -c 'commands' and do away with the fugly options (they should no longer be necessary or useful).
